# Не могу подключить поды в проект. Что я делаю не правильно?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, cocoapods, pod

Я пытаюсь добавить поды в свой проект, но почему-то после вызова команды  pod install мне пишет, что в директории проекта не найдено под файла, но на скриншоте видно, что он есть. В чем проблема
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Содержимое пода прикрепите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте переустановить ваш cocoapods.
Затем попробуйте снова установить ваш pod. Скорее всего вы просто не правильно его ставите.
Вот хорошее видео как пример.
[how to install pod](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZwRC7mqdNw)